# get List<CustomClass> from Page to User Control

Tags: c#, list, user-controls

i have a custom class List on my page code behind:

```
public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
```

now, i have also a user control on that page which is supposed to display that list.

how can i access the list from the usercontrol,
or, can i create a list directly in the usercontrol from the page?

my User Control codebehind:

```
public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public class Category
{
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

my Page codebehind:

```
public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Category MyCategory = new Category();
    MyCategory.category_id = 1;
    MyCategory.category = "sample";
    Categories.Add(MyCategory);
}
public class Category
{
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `Category` class declared twice, once in the page, once in the user control?

Comment: yes, since i though it should be passed the same.

Comment: Does that mean they are in different namespaces?

Comment: since one is under _default, and the other under _userControl, then yes, they are.

Comment: Why don't you just put it in a central location and use it in both places instead of having two exact same classes?  The reason you're getting the cast exception when trying Hasan's answer is because the list and the variable you're assigning it to are of different types.

Comment: the categories are taken from a mysql db, and i do all that work on the page, i just need to display them on the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since Hasan Khan has started helping me,
but never answered my extra questions... i had to find my own solution.

the way i did it at the end was instead of adding items to the list on the Page,
adding them directly to the user control like so:

```
filterControl.Categories.Add(new widgets_filter.Category{ category_id = "", category = ""});
```

i dont know if this is a good solution, but at least it works.

if somebody will supply a better answer ( with sample code ) , i will try and use them, meanwhile, this is what i have.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in your user control and assign the list to that property

```
MyUserControl.ListProperty = theList;
```

OR

Put the list as a public property in the page and access it via Page property in user contorl. You'll need to cast it to your page type first.

```
var theList = ((MyPage)Page).ListProperty
```

OR

Put the list in HttpContext.Current.Items and get it from there.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["theList"] = theList;
```

Comment: when doing your 1st suggestion, i get "cannot implify convert.."

Comment: in the 2nd example, i cannot access the list via Page.Categories even due that as you see it is defined as public in the page.

Comment: @domentic you may be accessing list before setting it. Check the order of events